# Avoid re-initialize values in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the below code, variable *xAxis* is re-initialized multiple times before every push into the array. How can i optimize this code?

```
var xAxis=1;
            vm.pnLreportingPlotData.push(plotModel.map(function(o){
                    return {x:xAxis++,y:o.PnLreporting};
                })
            );

            var xAxis=1;
            vm.var95PlotData.push(plotModel.map(function(o){
                    return { x:xAxis++, y:o.VaR95Total};
                })
            );

            var xAxis=1;
            vm.var99PlotData.push(plotModel.map(function(o){
                    var xAxis = 1;
                    return  { x:xAxis++, y:o.VaR99Total};
                })
            );
```

Comment: This question lacks context. What does this code accomplish? What are the inputs and outputs? See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the need for your `xAxis` variable through using the index when mapping:

```
vm.pnLreportingPlotData.push(plotModel.map(function (o, i) {
  return { x: i + 1, y: o.PnLreporting }
}

vm.var95Plotdata.push(plotModel.map(function (o, i) {
  return { x: i + 1, y: o.VaR95Total }
}

vm.var99PlotData.push(plotModel.map(function (o, i) {
  return { x: i + 1, y: o.VaR99Total }
}
```

[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) provides three arguments, `currentValue` (`o`), `index`, and `array` (which isn't needed in our example)

N.B. you did not need to keep declaring `xAxis` after you had done so the first time (no need for the multiple `var` declarations, they could simply become `xAxis = 1`)

While the above answers your question of how to avoid redeclaring `xAxis`, I've added a few additional comments below:

**Naming**

You could possibly benefit from using more descriptive variable names. It is not immediately obvious what variables such as `o` represent. Likewise, `i` could be changed to `index` if you found it helped readability.

Consistency:

- `var95Plotdata` uses lowercase 'd' for 'data', however `var99PlotData` capitializes it (is this a typo?)
- `VaR95Total` capitalizes both 'V' and 'R' - can this be changed to be consistent with your view model or is this coming from an external api?

**Extracting logic**

Since the logic is almost identical besides property names, you could extract the logic if you wanted:

```
function getPlotData(property) {
  // Ideally renaming `o` to whatever it represents
  return plotModel.map(function (o, index) {
    return { x: index + 1, y: o[property] }
  }))
}

vm.pnLreportingPlotData.push(getPlotData('PnLreporting'))
vm.var95Plotdata.push(getPlotData('vaR95Total'))
vm.var99PlotData.push(getPlotData('VaR99Total'))
```